# How to programatically store image in Gallery on Android 4.4

Tags: java, android, gallery

My code worked well on older Androids but gives and error on Android 4.4.
I've tried to copy the file to external storage but that doesn't help.
You can see in the log that the file is copied OK, but the `Bitmap` is likely not created properly because the code chokes on `Media.insertImage`.

Just note that this exact code works well if I use Intent to open the file in an application (thus the external storage must work well).

Also note, that I have these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**My code**

```
public static void storeImageToSystemGalery (String image_fullPathFileName) {
    try {
        Log.e(TAG, "Pp: CALLED: storeImageToSystemGalery (image_fullPathFileName=" + image_fullPathFileName +")");

        java.io.File internal_f = new java.io.File(image_fullPathFileName);
        Log.e(TAG, "Pp: internal_f: exists test=" + internal_f.exists());
        Log.e(TAG, "Pp: internal_f: canRead test=" + internal_f.canRead());


        File external_f = new File(parentActivity.getExternalFilesDir(null), "galery_shared.jpg");
        Log.e(TAG, "Pp: external_f.AbsolutePath=" + external_f.getAbsolutePath());
        _f_copy(internal_f, external_f);
        Log.e(TAG, "Pp: external_f: exists test=" + external_f.exists());
        Log.e(TAG, "Pp: external_f: canRead test=" + external_f.canRead());

        Uri imageURI = Uri.fromFile(external_f);

        android.graphics.Bitmap bmp = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(parentActivity.getContentResolver(), imageURI);
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(parentActivity.getContentResolver(), bmp, "Prstynek", "Muj prstynek");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.w(TAG, "FAILED to storeImageToSystemGalery: " + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


static private void _f_copy(File fin, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(fin);
    FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(dst);
    byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while ((len=in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

**Log dump:**

```
E/cocos2d.sharkintelligence.Helper__sharkCore( 5824): Pp: CALLED: storeImageToSystemGalery (image_fullPathFileName=/data/data/com.sharkintelligence.test.trivialdrive2/files/product_preview_shared.jpg)
E/cocos2d.sharkintelligence.Helper__sharkCore( 5824): Pp: internal_f: exists test=true
E/cocos2d.sharkintelligence.Helper__sharkCore( 5824): Pp: internal_f: canRead test=true
E/cutils  (  166): Failed to mkdirat(/Removable/MicroSD): Read-only file system
W/ContextImpl( 5824): Failed to ensure directory: /Removable/MicroSD/Android/data/com.sharkintelligence.test.trivialdrive2/files
E/cocos2d.sharkintelligence.Helper__sharkCore( 5824): Pp: external_f.AbsolutePath=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.sharkintelligence.test.trivialdrive2/files/galery_shared.jpg
W/Vold    (  166): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30
E/cocos2d.sharkintelligence.Helper__sharkCore( 5824): Pp: external_f: exists test=true
E/cocos2d.sharkintelligence.Helper__sharkCore( 5824): Pp: external_f: canRead test=true
D/dalvikvm( 5824): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2216K, 24% free 7501K/9764K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm( 5824): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 5824): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.358MB for 4187152-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 5824): GC_CONCURRENT freed 138K, 18% free 11452K/13856K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 7ms
E/MediaStore( 5824): Failed to insert image
E/MediaStore( 5824): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:611)
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:922)
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:669)
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:912)
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at com.sharkintelligence.android.app.Helper__sharkCore.storeImageToSystemGalery(Helper__sharkCore.java:295)
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender(Native Method)
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.onDrawFrame(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:91)
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
E/MediaStore( 5824):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
D/MediaProvider(  787): object removed 188
```

Comment: If you look at the first line of your logcat you know why.

Comment: It is advisable to give '_f_copy' a boolean return value and inspect that after use.

Comment: Further you are unclear in telling how far your ode flows and if there are exceptions/catches.

Comment: I've clarified the code (sorry for the original mess). Now you can see that the file is copied OK, but not inserted in the MediaStore...

Comment: `E/cutils  (  166): Failed to mkdirat(/Removable/MicroSD): Read-only file system
W/ContextImpl( 5824): Failed to ensure directory: /Removable/MicroSD/Android/data/com.sharkintelligence.test.trivialdrive2/files`. Well please comment yourself on these loggings. Where do they come from?

Comment: I wish I know where these logs come from. I copy the file different external location and the copy is successful as you can see from logs. The mentioned Failed messages are printed before insertImage() is called and I also see that insertImage() is the problematic part. My explanation is that the failed messages come from `getExternalFilesDir()` which tries to find available external space. This is obviously only my hypothesis. Do you know what is going on and can you point me to some solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have this functionality working somewhere? Seems like I'am the only one storing the image in gallery on Android 4.4 :-(

Comment: I see nothing wrong on your insertImage() and such code works for me on 4.4.2. You better look where those logs come from as they make no sense. getExternalFilesDir will not make them. And who is executing a mkdir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly got it working. Used this function: createExternalStoragePublicPicture()
from this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)